# c# are these parameters passed to c++ dll function correct?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, dll, parameters

hi i have a third part dll which functions make request to a dvr...I tried some functions but i got wrong results...i don't know if i'm wrong or the dll have problems..
from the dll docs:

```
int WINAPI tvcc_get_rec_days(int server_handle,struct Camera *video_camera,char **days,int
 *size);
```

char **days should be a not allocated character pointers array that will contain the days list 
int *size will be the length of array

I declared this function in c# like this

```
[DllImport(lib, EntryPoint = "@tvcc_get_rec_days$qqsip6Camerappcpi")]
static public extern int tvcc_get_rec_days(int server_handle,ref Camera video_camera,ref char*[]  days,ref int size);
```

now if I call the function like this:

```
static char*[] days;
static int size;
int returnvalue = GamsSdk.tvcc_get_rec_days(sh2,ref cameras[1],ref days,ref size);
```

i get the correct return value (function works good), size is 104 but days is not a 104 array!! days.length is always = 1 but if i try to read the first cell get null exception...i tried various modification in days and sometimes if i print the cell i get 0 or strange symbols...i also thought that what i get was the address of arrays but in any case i don't know how to get it...
any idea?

Comment: How is the `Camera` struct defined in the C# code? Have you added the `StructLayoutAttribute` to it?

Comment: Try using `StringBuilder` instead of `ref char*[]  days` in the declaration for the DllImport

Comment: yes this is not the problem...I take example code which tests some dll functions..i simply add code to test others...however docs says that camera is not used in that version of dll..

Comment: @MatthewWatson tried yet...if i call tostring() i get random symbols like **x(¡**

Comment: You may need to specify the CharSet for the dllimport statement, it defaults to Ansi. Do you know what charset your c++ dll operates in?

Comment: @Nanhydrin i don't know...but the dllimport was made by the dll creators...i just add this function import under many others...however you confirm that the parameters I pass are correct? i mean the types matching,pointers ecc?i'm not so good with c++

Comment: The only way to confirm that your parameters are correct is to try it out and see what you get. That you're getting something out of the StringBuilder is positive. If the documentation for the 3rd party dll doesn't specify what character encoding it uses then just try out a few different charsets and see if that changes the output.

Comment: @Nanhydrin the only think i know is that days format is DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: i had the prove that the dll is not bugged...other app (not done by me) works well...so the problem is parameter...i dont understand: isn't there a unique matching from char**[] c++ type and c#?

Comment: SOLVED!! where functions ask for char **s i put ref string s....where ask for char *s1  i put simply string s1..if i print s i get the results (all together in one string)